# Disabling user interaction with a UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

While my application runs a brief animation, I don't want the user to be able to click on anything. In my view controller I can use

```
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

to block most interaction, but it doesn't prevent the buttons in the toolbar/navbar from firing events.

I can't just disable the buttons, since this has a distracting visual impact (the buttons are grayed out).

How might I briefly suspend interaction with ALL of the controls?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `-beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` and `-endIgnoringInteractionEvents` on your instance of `UIApplication`. This is exactly what classes like `UINavigationController` do when animating a push to a new view controller. To get your particular instance of `UIApplication`, use the `+sharedApplication` method on the `UIApplication` class. Consider this example.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```